# How to take user input of multiples fields in LIST<> in C# dynamically not hard coded like i did the code below?

Tags: c#, .net, list, input, dynamic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Branches
{
    public class Branch
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }  

        public Branch() { }

        public Branch(int id, string code, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Code = code;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<Branch> br = new List<Branch>(){
                new Branch(){ Id=401, Code="SBI120800", Name="Chembur West" },
                new Branch(){ Id=402, Code="SBI120700", Name="Chembur East" },
                new Branch(){ Id=403, Code="SBI120900", Name="Govandi West" },
                new Branch(){ Id=404, Code="SBI120500", Name="Govandi East" },
                new Branch(){ Id=405, Code="SBI120400", Name="Andheri West" },
                new Branch(){ Id=406, Code="SBI120300", Name="Andheri East" },
            };

            foreach (var branches  in br)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(branches.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the string split  to separate around a comma : string[] inputs = line.Split(newchar[] {','}).ToArray();

Comment: I am guessing you want those values asked to the user. Create 3 questions and add the answers to variables, at the end, just push the values into the List using new Branch(){Id=var1, Code=var2, Name=var3};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A snippet that trims spaces, uses commas as delimiters between individual fields and newliness between different Branch objects, checks for duplicate IDs, codes, and names, and checks the code format according to the format I saw in your above code (`SBIxxxxxx`):

```
// This requires LINQ.
List<Branch> br = new List<Branch>(); // You can replace 'new List<Branch>()' with 'new()' if you're using C# 9.0 or newer.
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the ID, code, and name of the branch, seperated by commas, or enter an empty string to finish:");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == String.Empty)
        break;
    string[] entry = line.Split(',');
    entry[0] = entry[0].Trim();
    entry[1] = entry[1].Trim();
    entry[2] = entry[2].Trim();
    entry[1] = entry[1].ToUpper();
    if (entry.Length != 3)
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number of arguments.");
    else if (!Int32.TryParse(entry[0], out int id))
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid ID entered.");
    else if (entry[2] == String.Empty)
        Console.WriteLine("Name must not be blank.");
    else if (!(entry[1].StartsWith("SBI") && Int32.TryParse(entry[1].Remove(0, 3), out int code) && code >= 100000 && code <= 999999))
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid code format.");
    else if ((from e in br
                where ((id == e.Id)
                    || (entry[1] == e.Code)
                    || (entry[2] == e.Name))
                select e).Count() > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate ID, code, or name entered.");
    else
        br.Add(new Branch(id, entry[1], entry[2])); // Again, you can replace 'new Branch()' with 'new()' if you're using C# 9.0 or newer.
}
foreach (Branch b in br)
    Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you find bugs with this code, please report them.

Comment: I dont how to thank you but you people are doing wonderful social service for IT freshers. Even google search doesnt provide relevant content.Thanks a lot !

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you should probably check if the "name" field is blank using something like `if (entry[2] == String.Empty) Console.WriteLine("Name must not be blank.");`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Branch> br = new List<Branch>();
while(true) 
{
 Console.WriteLine("Please provide Id")
 var id =  Console.ReadLine();
 ... // Ask other questions 
 br.Add( new Branch { Id =id, ...});
 Console.WriteLine("Would you like to add another branch? Y/N");
 if(Console.ReadKey().ToLower() == 'n') break;
}
```